# Where Does Nik HDR Efex Pro 2 Save?

Tags: software, troubleshooting

Google recently made their suite available for free and I found how to open files with HDR Efex Pro 2. I get to tweak parameters until it looks a certain way and hit *Save*. A scrollbar appears, progresses to the end and closes. No success or error message is shown.

Now, where is the output? Cant find it anywhere. Nothing appears on the Desktop, Image, Documents, TMP or TEMP folders. This is on Windows 7 64-bit using the 32-bit or 64-bit executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Nik Tools without the adobe software is a pain, though as Michael points out they should save back over the original file.

A file search on the name might yield something (or it may not); but, a surefire way to find out is using the `SysInternals` tool called [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), written by a (now) Microsoft employee it will tell you exactly what process on your system is accessing which file as it does it.

You just install it, run as admin, hit save (in Nik Efex) and stop the trace in Process Explorer when the save is complete.  You might have to hunt around a little to narrow it down and filter out all the other applications/file accesses but if the file is being written you'll definitely see it there.

Comment: Thanks to Process Explorer, I found out that the process actually crashes at the end of the Save action. As mentioned earlier, Save As works.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use the "Save As" dialog it overwrites the original file.

In the case of using it is a plugin with an application such as Lightroom, it will overwrite the TIFF or JPEG that LR generates when it exports the image to the plugin.

For more please see: [Can the Nik Collection be used without Photoshop or Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75907/can-the-nik-collection-be-used-without-photoshop-or-lightroom/75916#75916)

Comment: Just tried it again on a Windows 7 system with images on a writable partition (my original attempt was on a read-only file system) and it just doesn't do this. Original files are untouched. *Save As* works as you describe though, so I am still puzzled.

Comment: Your system may have other measures in place that prevent files from being overwritten? Are you looking at the before/after of an original raw file or of a jpeg or tiff file generated and exported by LR to HDR Efex? Where does LR place those tiff/jpeg files? If they are in a temp folder the temp file will be overwritten.

Comment: No. This one is pretty much vanilla system. I created a folder with only 3 JPEG images shot in-camera copied from an SDXC card. The files are dated roughly 1 month ago and that does not change after saving. Opening the files validate that these are the original -2, 0, +2 exposed files and look completely different from the one obtained by *Save As*.

Comment: It's possible the HDR Efex Pro 2 module doesn't mirror the behaviour of the other modules in the Nik Collection. It is the only one that has a 'Save As" dialog. The others only have a "Save" option which, when used, overwrites the original file and closes the executable. But the "Save" command should at least update a temporary file somewhere. Have you tried the method outlined in the linked question above to see what happens on your system when you hit "Save" using the other modules?

Answer (score 2):

I use the Windows7 system.  And the HDR Pro 2 only has the SAVE button, no SAVE AS IS button.

I found that the output file of Nik HDR Pro 2 is saved at:

Computer/Windows7_OS/Users/(name of user)/My Documents/original file name_HDR.tif

Comment: That's where I found it in Windows 10 as well: C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you WHERE the files was save on your system, but you might try this route to FIND the saved image. I've had to do this in the past.

Just use the SEARCH bar in Windows and type in the file name (or any part of the file name that you remember) and see if it finds your file. If you find it, open the file, clickon "Save As", and then note the file path ... or save in a location of your choosing.